# How to create server for GCM project in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating a project on [Google Cloud Messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Messaging) (GCM) and am following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html).

I am done with the client-side work and set up the device on the client side. Also I had registered the device using the following code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, "483910217912");
        Log.d(tag, "Registered");
    }
    else {
        Log.v(tag, "Already registered");
    }
}
```

Now I am stuck at a point to create server for my GCM project. Note that I am creating a project to notify when a new message is received. However, I had not implemented the service to receive a message, but I will implement it when the server setting is finished.

Comment: @LalitPoptani why dont u put this as an answer. i think this is comprehensive.

Comment: thanx for the answer. that means, i first need to install apache tomcat. is it necessary. and please explain point 4.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would insist you to test the demo that is being provided on the develpers site. I had just created a demo sample based on that with all the steps that one should follow for executing the demo sample. You can check [my blog](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-steps-to-run-gcm-demo.html) and also find the source from [my github](https://github.com/lalit3686/GCMDemo).

Comment: i have seen u r code .what i have to on server side and i am confused please help me

Answer (score 6):

You can create a GCM server in Android using the blog post *[Google cloud Messaging (GCM) tutorial](http://android.amolgupta.in/2012/07/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial.html)* , but I would prefer to use [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) for server side code. You can create a GCM Server in [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) (PHP) in easy steps:

1. Create a server key from the Google API console page.
2. Identify the device token of a device for which this message is sent to.

You can find the easy steps in *[How to implement a GCM PHP push server for Android](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/07/gcm-php-push-server.html)* to implement the push server.

Comment: this app is in android platform. does it makes any difference.!

Comment: As php is a server side scripting language it is preferable to use php  as server and client as a android code.

Comment: what IDE should i use for it. Does Netbeans works or Eclipse.!

Comment: You can use Eclipse as IDE, but for PHP script execution you need WAMP server on your machine.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this code

```
package yourpackage.android.gcm.server;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Notify {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            Sender sender = new Sender("AIzaSyCn3N2OIm-EDtiGwTyQfSIB8NRvDtIOx30");

            ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
//add you deviceID
            devicesList.add("APA91bELVJbxB_NLnLbTkkkX87SDdkJc6OfCN2slhC9t4cLq-KA32eGgiW4-Gi--ZEsEMKIh0AtYJMs5rQGswfm3cH1qK853WcpV98bkaplAaC5AiycDmifuVFSRl21vgf-Rqj0dCrFF");
                        //devicesList.add("APA91bHIdM4XGqrjJLTuwCX5OOrTYG4ACXYEVkZDM1bPs5qFdzJP4Bpql-sZqyKB8BU7fDtdxB84aTygHLyASYg_XNY6lqrcA4wj4sZHJXGVFzz_0UEADMfFCx9NAfRZxunIYso_dkBa");
            //APA91bFA-i2l3iEMnIBs0JK80pTLHOsE7p1s-DysRpKGas1MQOVILyIs9xwY7soysSWGz5Uif68uXR6F5Xn0tCTYesv78uQZxhC310a1cvf8aFohhfMGY6awbOSg3t1GRz2i3U-8kVSF
            // Use this line to send message without payload data
            // Message message = new Message.Builder().build();

            // use this line to send message with payload data
            Message message = new Message.Builder()
                    //.collapseKey("message")
                    //.timeToLive(241000)
                    .delayWhileIdle(true)
                    .addData("message", "Your message send")
                    .build();


                   /**/
            // Use this code to send to a single device
            // Result result = sender
            // .send(message,
            // "APA91bGiRaramjyohc2lKjAgFGpzBwtEmI8tJC30O89C2b3IjP1CuMeU1h9LMjKhmWuZwcXZjy1eqC4cE0tWBNt61Kx_SuMF6awzIt8WNq_4AfwflaVPHQ0wYHG_UX3snjp_U-5kJkmysdRlN6T8xChB1n3DtIq98w",
            // 1);

            // Use this for multicast messages
            MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
            //sender.send(message, devicesList, 0);

            System.out.println(result.toString());
            if (result.getResults() != null) {
                int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
                if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
                }
            } else {
                int error = result.getFailure();
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanx, it will definitely help me in the later part of the project to send messages. but now the point of concern is _how to create a server for the project_ .

Comment: if i use this server side as android application ,, Does i need to merge the classes (client , server) together in one package ??
-----
And What is the best for the server side (Asp.net or this one)  ??

Answer (score 5):

The `com.google.android.gcm.server` library is deprecated. Just encode your message to JSON object and POST it to GCM URL https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

JSON example:

```
 {
   "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",...],
   "data" : {
     "Team" : "Portugal",
     "Score" : "3",
     "Player" : "Varela",
   },
 }
```

Here is more http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Answer (score 4):

You can find sample code for gcm-client and gcm-server in the Android SDK directory. It is good point to get started. Directory is :

> path_to_android_sdk/extras/google/gcm/samples

Comment: I have created the client side app. but how to use the gcm-demo-server from the android samples. do i need to import the project to the netbeans. Also if there some requirements to install the server engine.

Comment: use this tutorial to set up server side code.http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html#server-setup

Comment: i have gone through it. but i could not understand the 3rd and the 4th point.

Comment: these steps is used to generate .war file in order to run it on the application server. Do you have server side experience? Otherwise it will be hard to develop it.

Comment: I have studies about servelets a bit, though i dont have experience in developing server side applications.

Comment: @parvin will u please explain where i will get the code path_to_android_sdk/extras/google/gcm/samples i am not getting this

Comment: @Gaurav You can find the code in the Android SDK directory.First find the directory where you installed Android SDK and inside it you can see the extras folder.

Comment: fine thanks i got that. what i have to do on server side ..how i will broadcast the msg from there

Comment: I have downloaded the latest ADT (64) for Windows but this folder does not exist. Did they remove this?

Answer (score 3):

```
In your main function implement following code to send push notification to your app

final String apiKey = "specify your  api key generated by gcm";

To make http connection to gcm using following code

 URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/g...");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key="+apiKey);

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

JSON message format accepted by GCM

String input = "{\"registration_ids\" : [\"Specify token you got from GCM\"],\"data\" : {\"message\": \"hai  welcome\"},}";

To send notification

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

In your client app you need to have proper BroadcastReceiver  class to receive the message sent from GCM
```