# How to implementing server for Google Cloud Messaging to send Push notification android studio

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement push notification feature in existing android app.

I am following https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client
tutorial.

As of now so far so good.

Now to send the push notification we must have to implement client and server.

I found the tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints. I followed it but getting lots of dependency errors in android studio.

Can anybody tell me how to implement server side? 
Is there any better tutorial for the same?
Am I on the right track?

I refered below question on stackoverfolw but not satisfied...

[How to create server for GCM project in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836844/how-to-create-server-for-gcm-project-in-android)

[Android push service, implementing the gcm server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902217/android-push-service-implementing-the-gcm-server-side) (A PHP server, I don't have PHP knowledge , so would like to implement in JAVA launguage)

http://myandroidpoint.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-google-cloud-messaging-server.html

> **In short, My client is ready, stuck at implementing server.**

Thanks!
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to read the lateset documentation: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server GCM has changed a lot over the past few years and a lot of "helper libs" out there  are out of date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you have created a new project at Google Developers Console and taken note of 2 values: Project Number, which will be used as SENDER_ID in a client project; and API server key (created at Credentials), which will be used as API_KEY in a server project.

You can find more about basic server project with my answers at the following questions. In the second link, you will find sample code for a server project in Java:

[Adding Google Cloud Messagin (GCM) for Android - Registration process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322631/adding-google-cloud-messagin-gcm-for-android-registration-process/32323334#32323334)

[How to implement a GCM Hello World for Android using Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299997/how-to-implement-a-gcm-hello-world-for-android-using-android-studio)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Respect dependencies : I had two problem and I solved ( google.code:findbugs and annotations)

In the first case I deleted directly the "compile testnespresso" and in the second case I changed the  version of appcompat ( i had 24)  :

Now it's my build.gradle (app):

```
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
```

'

After I followed the steps in the links you posted and it works perfectly I have a server and I can send messages....( I deployed appengine )